# BAD signature when installing specific package with apk after forced poweroff

Tags: package-management, alpine-linux, corruption, signature, apk-tools

Earlier I was playing around with my PinePhone running postmarketOS Edge (based on Alpine Linux Edge) and while installing `gcc-go` using apk via the command `sudo apk add gcc-go` the phone froze. As such, I did a forced power off and booted it back up. Now, however, when I do `sudo apk add gcc-go` it gives me the following output:

```
(1/3) Installing libucontext (0.11-r0)
ERROR: libucontext-0.11-r0: BAD signature
(2/3) Installing libgo (10.2.0-r5)
ERROR: libgo-10.2.0-r5: BAD signature
(3/3) Installing gcc-go (10.2.0-r5)
ERROR: gcc-go-10.2.0-r5: BAD signature
3 errors; 2567 MiB in 711 packages
```

Go is subsequently then not installed, and when adding any package — including ones that aren't `gcc-go` — I get the same errors. It does stop if I do `sudo apk del gcc-go`, but if I subsequently attempt to install `gcc-go` via the same command as earlier the same error arises. It also persists if I add `--no-cache` to the install operation.

Why is this, and what might I do to resolve it so that `gcc-go` can be installed?

Comment: the Pinephone with PostmarketOS rocks the sh*@ out :-D

Comment: @scjorge glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearing my apk package cache by deleting all files in `/var/cache/apk` resolved this.

```
# rm /var/cache/apk/*
```

You can probably also get away by just deleting the relevant packages from said location by doing something like this.

```
# rm /var/cache/apk/libucontext-0.11-r0.*.apk \
     /var/cache/apk/libgo-10.2.0-r5.*.apk \
     /var/cache/apk/gcc-go-10.2.0-r5.*.apk
```

(`*` there because apk puts a seemingly random hash in that place)